# Why doesn't Postgres Group By NULL select counts?

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, group-by

I am trying to get a count of each value in a table using the following SQL:

```
SELECT col, COUNT(col)
FROM table 
GROUP BY col
```

(There's a WHERE clause in the real code, but it has no impact).

When I run this I get results like so:

```
a      - 5
b      - 4
<null> - 0
```

It doesn't matter how many null entries I have, it always shows a count of 0.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Note: I have a workaround for this (I just union a SELECT null, count(*) FROM table WHERE col is null), but it feels like a hack to me.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Figured it out.
Changed the code to use COUNT(*) instead of COUNT(col).

COUNT(col) was not counting any null rows, all other aggregation methods also eliminate nulls from the result set.